# Xamarin.iOS - Exception stack trace lines are zero when buidling for AppStore (using TestFlight for internal users)

Tags: ios, xamarin, stack-trace, lines, testflight

When building for Appstore in Xamarin Studio and deploying it in Testflight for internal testers, I intentionally throw an exception and send the stack trace to my server, but lines are zero:

```
  at iOS.SettingsScreen.<SettingsScreen>m__6 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoTouch.Dialog.StringElement.Selected (MonoTouch.Dialog.DialogViewController dvc, UIKit.UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoTouch.Dialog.DialogViewController.Selected (Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoTouch.Dialog.DialogViewController+Source.RowSelected (UIKit.UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, IntPtr principal, IntPtr delegate) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I disabled LLVM (I think it already was disabled) but I still don't see the lines. I attached an image. I may configured it wrong.

[image]

How can I get the lines numbers? Thank you, I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to upload the dSYM file to Test Flight